Artifacts appear when using the subsurface modifier with a hole
An artifact appears when Iusing subsurf

What exactly is the artifact? Without showing the original mesh, we can't know what it's supposed to look like :) Please share a screenshot of the mesh and topology before applying the subsurface modifier as well. Better yet, you can upload your .blend file using the [edit]or.

hope this helps. The large Ngon in the image needs more cuts for it to fill properly. 
You can ctrl T the face to triangulate it, or you can knife cut some manual cuts for more control.
